# Python: How to merge 3 JSON files that some of the data has the same key

Tags: json, python-3.x, merge

Python: How to merge 3 JSON files that some of the data has the same key, I want to keep the third file json file and merge them into one, I have three json files :

```
file1.json
{
  "A111": {
       "KEY1" : "AAA1"
       "KEY2" : "AAA2"
  }
}


file2.json
{
  "B222": {
       "KEY1" : "BBB1"
       "KEY2" : "BBB2"
  }
}

file3.json
{
  "A111": {
       "KEY1" : "CCC1"
       "KEY2" : "CCC2"
  }
}

#================================================#
I NEED THE OUTPUT OF MERGED JSON FILE:
filemerged.json
{
  "A111": {
       "KEY1" : "CCC1"
       "KEY2" : "CCC1"
  }
  "B222": {
       "KEY1" : "BBB1"
       "KEY2" : "BBB2"
  }
}
```

Need to megre them and keep the last json update

Comment: Why did the second A111 become a child of B222 and where did the BBB* go?

Comment: Wrong posted, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

In python a Json also behaves like a dictionary.

You can simply use `update()` of dictionary.

```
j1={
  "A111": {
       "KEY1" : "AAA1",
       "KEY2" : "AAA2"
  }
}

j2={
  "B222": {
       "KEY1" : "BBB1",
       "KEY2" : "BBB2"
  }
}

j3={
  "A111": {
       "KEY1" : "CCC1",
       "KEY2" : "CCC2"
  }
}

j3.update(j2)

print(j3)
{'A111': {'KEY1': 'CCC1', 'KEY2': 'CCC2'},
 'B222': {'KEY1': 'BBB1', 'KEY2': 'BBB2'}}
```

Comment: @user975248  please accept my answer by clicking tick mark.

Comment: you are missing `j1`, in this happy case it works, but not in general